# Display AND Capture STDOUT

Tags: perl, stdout

What I am doing seems, to me, as if it should be fairly simple so I am probably going to facepalm after it is answered. With that being said:

I am trying to call an outside (non-PERL) function from within my PERL script. I would like to have the STDOUT from the function both printed to the console (as it occurs) and also I would like to capture that information and return it to the original PERL script that called it.

Attempted solutions include:

```
#does not return the output
my @output = system($cmd);

#does not display the output as it occurs
my @output = `$cmd`;

#does not display the output as it occurs
eval {$pid = open3($Input, $Output, $Error, $cmd); }; die "open3: $@\n" if $@;
```

Does anyone know a method that will both print the STDOUT to the screen (in realtime) and also capture the STDOUT and return it to the original source of the call?

Comment: @aschepler You are correct! That is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: Incidentally, how do I close this question or mark it as a duplicate?

Comment: You can't do that yet. When you have enough reputation, you can vote to close. It takes five votes to close a question. Users with a gold badge in a tag can duplicate close questions in that tag on their own. You should check the [faq] (reading all of it gives a badge). And https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges is a nice overview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Capture::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Capture::Tiny) can do that. You can either just `capture_stdout` and `print` it yourself afterwards, or use `tee_stdout` to have it print and capture at the same time.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Capture::Tiny 'tee_stdout';

my $stdout = tee_stdout sub { `ls -lah` }; # prints
print "ok\n" if $stdout =~ m/\./;          # matches
```